# How to make an object constatnt at collapsing toolbar layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making an app that develop a profile activity
my profile activity has a collapse toolbar layout, how to make some view constant under the toolbar while scrolling the screen, these are screen shots of what I mean 
[before collapsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhvZg.png)

[This what I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdpvr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , just create layout named `activity_profile_detail` and past this code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    //your main content here

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I put NestedScrollView after AppBarLayout, but every thing get scrolled in the nested view. I want to put linearlayout in the NestedScrollView and make it positioned under the tollbar while scrolling the rest

Comment: see this example http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator , mayble it heplful to you

Comment: If it helpful you , please mark this answer **correct**